# To find a prime palindrome number

Tags: python, list, primes

I have to print nth prime palindrome number with the help of this program, where n is number given by the user but I have a problem in this program, as it is taking much time to print the  answer.

```
n=int(input())
l=[]
for i in range(1,1000000):
    y=True
    if str(i)==str(i)[::-1]:
        if i>=2:
            for j in range(2,i):
                if i%j==0:
                    y=False
                    break     
            if y:
                l.append(i)
print("Your Prime Palindrome Number Is:",l[n-1])
```

How can I make this code time efficient?

Comment: one way is caculate primes first then check palindrome condition, second approach is save found prime, and match existing number against them

Comment: You don't `n` in the code, so imagine the user ask for the 5th one, and you calculate maybe 100 of them, you need to stop when you have the nth one

Comment: another optimization would be to only check until the square root of `i` for the primes, because `i` can't be divisible by a greater number

Comment: Most numbers are not palindromes. You can iterate over the palindromes directly by iterating over the first halves of the numbers and then reflecting to get the second half.

Comment: In order to avoid testing some number, you can also use the fact that every palindrome number of even length (1221, 88, 3333) will be divisible by eleven (check the criteria for the divisibility by 11 online)

Comment: No multi-digit prime can end in 0, 2, 4, 5, 6 or 8 since it will have a divisor of 2 or 5. Hence no prime palindrome can ever start with those digits, except the single digit primes 2 and 5. That will let you eliminate a lot of multi-digit number without prime testing. For instance, any four digit number from 2000 to 2999 cannot give a prime palindrome, so there is no need to test that range.

Answer (score 1):

The first part of this code is not specific to this question. It's a general purpose strategy for testing prime numbers. It's faster than *sympy.isprime()* for values lower than ~500,000 (Python 3.11.1 on Intel Xeon) after which the *sympy* version betters this implementation.

```
from math import sqrt, floor

def isprime(n):
    if n < 2:
        return False
    if n == 2 or n == 3:
        return True
    if n % 2 == 0 or n % 3 == 0:
        return False
    for i in range(5, floor(sqrt(n))+1, 6):
        if n % i == 0 or n % (i + 2) == 0:
            return False
    return True
```

Now you need something to test for a palindrome. This function will return True if the string representation of the object is palindromic.

```
def ispalindrome(o):
    return (_ := str(o)) == _[::-1]
```

And this is the main part of the program. As 2 is the only even prime number, let's treat that as a special case. Otherwise start with 3 and just test subsequent odd numbers.

```
N = int(input('Enter value for N: '))

if N > 0:
    if N == 1:
        print(2)
    else:
        p = 3
        while True:
            if isprime(p) and ispalindrome(p):
                if (N := N - 1) == 1:
                    print(p)
                    break
            p += 2
```

**Sample output:**

```
Enter value for N: 11
313
```